# What is difference between Android cache memory and Android apps cache memory

Tags: android

Could anyone please tell me what is android cache and apps cache because when we talk about cache clean apps then what it do, is cache clean concept is cleaning apps cache or else like memory management Primary storage,RAM,Cache are different and as i know cache size small because it is very costly. so i want to be clear that what exactly the concept of cache in android OS.

Answer (score 1):

The cache is basically a temporary storage area for an application while it's running -- it can store things like temporary images downloaded from the internet. Clearing it shouldn't really have much of an effect from a user perspective. Clearing the data, however, will remove any user data, databases, etc -- this includes things like account settings, persistent preferences, etc. Clearing the data should revert the application back to it's state as it was when you first installed it.

As an example, assume we have a Twitter application. Clearing the cache might delete any profile images for people you're following, so when you look at your timeline again, they'll have to be retrieved from the internet again. Clearing the data would remove any information at all, including your login information, who you're following, whether or not you want to be notified of new tweets, and things like that.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.